# Azure Runbook Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll'

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook

I have a very simple piece of code I am trying to run from an Azure Runbook but when I do, it results in the following error message

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context."
```

Code:

```
workflow test
{
        
    inlinescript {
        try
        {
            "Logging in to Azure..."
            Connect-AzAccount -Identity
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }


        $ServerName = "sqlserverinstance.database.windows.net"
        $DB = "database_instance"
        $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token
        $token

       Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $DB -AccessToken $token -Query "some query"
}
}
```

I am using a Powershell Workflow runbook running 5.1. I have updated the SQLServer module as well with no luck. I don't run into this issue when I run things from the Azure Cloud Shell. Another thing, when I run the command using the -Credentials argument, it works. I want to use an access token though; hence why I am following the approach above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various of reasons that can block SQL server to connect to the database and get the result.

***Need to check & resolve:***

1. First of all, You need to be the admin of the account and add "*sql DB contributor, Sql server contributor*" for sql server.

[image]

2. Assign server system identity to the SQL server and  give the "***Directory Readers***" access to the server identity by referring to [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers).
3. To run SQL commands in a runbook or connect to a SQL server, you need to use the template which specifies a connection string.

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Check if you enabled system identity for automation accounts as you are trying to connect with `connect-azaccount -identity`
5. As you are trying to connect through Azure AD, register a new app registration by visiting `AzureAD -> App registrations -> New registration` and enable `API permissions`.

[image]

*After checking the above workaround, I tried below script and able to connect successfully as shown:*

```
connect-Azaccount -identity
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://<server>.database.windows.net).Token
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance '<server>.database.windows.net' `
-Database '<Servername>'
-AccessToken $token `
-Query "<query>"
```

***Output:***

[image]

[Reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/invoke-sqlcmd-with-azure-automation-for-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3633548)